# React js: How can i apply style on tags between select options in html?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to style span wrapped between option tag

```
  <select>
    <option value="option1">Active Wallet <span style={{fontWeight:'bold!important'}}>mBTC</span></option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only a few style attributes that can be applied to this element.

You have to use some external plugin/library,

There is more info: [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)